# The site is threatening me with edit suspension over automated rejections caused by conflicts

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, rejected-edits

I'm quite active on the main Stack Overflow site, especially within the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

Beginners usually post their code without proper formatting, making it harder
for us to read their code and give them help properly.

That's why I edit the questions. I mainly indent the code properly, so
that the OP learns how to do it and other users have a better time reading the
code.

Because I still don't have 2000 reputation points, my edit suggestions go into peer review. That's fine with me, but sometimes peer review is slow and other users with 2000+ reputation do the same edit. In that case my suggestion is rejected (at least I think that's the reason).

In the last week it happened to me at least 3 times that I made an edit
suggestion with proper code indentation which got rejected. In these 3 cases
another user with more reputation made the same edit as me (properly indenting
the code) and my suggestion got rejected. At least that's why I think
why my suggestion was rejected. Looking at this [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18482295), it says that it was rejected, because *"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"*.

Is that the reason why this particular suggestion got rejected?

Yesterday I saw a post with some nice visuals and I wanted to know how the
author of the answer managed to do that, so I clicked on *Edit* just to see
the markdown source code. Then I saw this warning:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> Warning! Some of your previous edits were rejected. Please review your recently-rejected edits before continuing. Too many rejected edits may cause your editing privileges to be suspended.

And indeed I have 3 recent rejections, all with the same message, all rejected
after a user with more reputation made the same edit. So now I'm worried that
if I suggest another edit, it might get rejected and my privileges suspended.

Is this what is really happening? Why are my suggestions being rejected? Or
is there another reason and if so, how can I see the reason, so
that I can improve my suggestions?

Comment: This might be a bug. [Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste/182983#182983)

Comment: @BSMP thanks for the link. But now I'm little confused. It says at some point that the issue has been fixed, but people are still complaining about me. If it were fixed, I shouldn't see the warning, yet I do.

Comment: *I shouldn't see the warning, yet I do* Right, that's why I think this could be a bug. Something's gone wrong.

Comment: This also falls under the remit of 2k+ rep users not reviewing the other edits before posting an edit while an edit pending the question, perhaps SO should inform the users there is a pending edit on this please review it before submitting your edit. and take them to the review so they can review or they can review and edit if they need to...

Comment: You've done nothing wrong; you've just been *remarkably* unlucky in that you've encountered 3 edit conflicts in the course of your first 10 edits. (For comparison, I've made 2184 edits, made hundreds of edit suggestions back before I got full editing privileges, and have *never* encountered an edit conflict; I don't even really know how they work.) The system should not be treating these in the same way as rejections by reviewers for the purpose of suspending editing; that's a bug, IMO, just one that perhaps nobody other than you has ever been in a position to notice.

Comment: @MartinBarker I think other SE sites have that. SO doesn't? It displays as `edit (1)` and on hovering over the link, the title is "there is 1 pending edit suggestion" or something similar.

Comment: Probably the bug is fixed, but the warning is not. If you get suspended edit, you can probably ask some moderator to remove the suspension.

Comment: @user202729 it has that but it does not force users who are able to review the review system before allowing them to edit that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: get to work and go get that 2000 rep. It's not that far away.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ha ha, yes sir! ... I've been "working" very hard in the last couple of weeks,  but gaining reputation points is hard, especially when work for a living.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. What can I do to report this bug to the SO developers? Using Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Pablo You can probably just change the last paragraph (give or take) of this post to ask for it to be fixed and point to the post linked above and tag this with [meta-tag:bug] (if there weren't a post saying it's supposed to work a different way, it would be a [meta-tag:feature-request]).

Comment: @MartinBarker The process is the same on all sites. It's possible for a 2k+ user to force an edit while there's a pending edit, but it is more complex to do so, and you have to know how. The ability to do so is useful, in some situations. *Normally*, if the 2k+ user tries to begin an edit after there's a pending edit, the 2k+ user will be presented with the pending edit to review rather than being directly able to edit. If a user is in the middle of an edit and another edit is applied, then the user still editing is informed via a notice-banner. I'm not certain this is shown (continued)

Comment: when an edit is suggested by a < 2k user, as it's not an actual applied edit. However, even in the case where the first edit is immediately applied (OP or 2k+ user), communicating it's existence takes time. It's significantly more likely that this is an issue with the existence of the pending edit not propagating in time for the other user to be informed, or that they are not informed of a new pending edit, rather than multiple users (2x 2k+, 1x OP) forcing edits, or saving over known existing edits. All of the rejected-by-Community edits were due to an edit that came in <2.5 minutes later.

Comment: @Makyen I certainly did not get any warning while editing that the OP or another 2k+ user edited the question. In fact, after saving my edit, I was redirected to the question and the usual remark about peer review appeared. After a while (not sure if <2.5 minutes later) I say again that my edit was rejected. One 2k+ user even apologized to me in the comments for revoking my edit. I'm not quote sure what you are trying to tell in your second comment, though.

Comment: @Pablo You saved your edit first. You would not get a notice-banner saying there was another edit saved, because there wasn't. A notice-banner is shown if an edit is saved by another user while you are editing. People are not informed that they are editing at the same time as someone else. [Your 3 rejected-by-community edits](//stackoverflow.com/users/1480131/pablo?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) all had another user save a different draft shortly after you did (48s (OP), 81s (2k+ user), 142s (2k+ user)). They, may, or may not, have been informed in that time that you had made an edit.

Comment: @Makyen ah ok, I get what you mean.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Looks like a bug

Your editor stats show 17 edit suggestions: 13 approved and 4 rejected.  However, not all of these are still visible; probably because some were on posts that were later deleted.

Your [suggested edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480131/pablo?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) shows 10 visible edit suggestions: 7 approved and 3 rejected.

The 3 visible rejected edits ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18482295); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18459399); [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18443409)) were all rejected for the reason that you've described:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Then, there's a fourth rejection that's not visible.

Apparently these rejections shouldn't have counted toward a ban (and presumably not a ban warning), per a post from 2013-06-04:

> We now ignore any suggested edits that were rejected by the Community User due to an edit conflict when determining whether someone should be banned from submitting suggested edits.
>
> -[@Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144066/emmett)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/351012)  to ["Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste) on SE.Meta (2013-06-04)

So if you're getting a warning, then either:

1. That warning's based off the 1 rejection that doesn't appear in your history.
2. It's a bug.

Even if that one rejection was an actual rejection, it doesn't seem like it should've resulted in a warning.  So, looks like a bug.

Comment: I think I can remember that way back around when I created the SO account, I made an edit that got rejected, but I'm not sure. It's funny that 4 suggestions are gone from my history, perhaps the question was deleted. Anyway, after reading many of the comments and the other links, I've decided to create a "bug report" later. I don't want to edit my question to do this, a new post where I present the evidence would be better (I think).

Comment: Based on your excellent answers lately, I suppose this problem will resolve itself in a couple of weeks. Better hurry with that bug report, else you cannot reproduce it :)

Answer (score 20):

So, the good news is, you were never in any actual danger of being banned, for [the reasons Nat stated in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361838/the-site-is-threatening-me-with-edit-suspension-over-automated-rejections-caused/361887#361887).

The bad news is, the *warnings* are based on a completely different bit of logic, which had a bug that caused it to count rejections caused by edit conflicts.

The worse news is, this bug was introduced 3.5 years ago, when we switched from storing the reason for Community-user rejections in a comment field to storing them in a typed column, and neglected to actually retrieve that column when figuring up whether a given user qualified for a warning.

In short, we haven't been banning anyone undeservedly... But we've probably scared a good few for no good reason.

The *great* news is that Adam Lear has now submitted a fix for this bug, which should roll out in the next build. So thanks to your report, no one should ever see this again after today.