# Post somehow edited while I'm making edit suggestion, no notification

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

This is the second time something like this has happened to me, and I'm kind of getting annoyed that I'm getting rejected edits on my record because of this.

So I came across a question in a review queue, where the OP posted code that [contains zero indenting](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49709924/1). I made an edit suggestion where I indented the code properly. Then, my edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19363257). It turns out, the post was somehow edited before I finished my suggestion. So when I submitted the suggestion, it was an edit of the post after the other edit. A user indented the code in a slightly different way than I did, so it did not trigger the 6 character limit. Therefore my edit got rejected because it didn't really change anything.

I had no way of knowing that this edit occurred. There was no "This post has been edited" message in the review queue or when I was making the suggestion. I had received notifications before, so I thought that this was supposed to be a feature. Some related feature requests people have helpfully directed me to in the comments seem to also show that this is already a feature: [Get notified of edit conflicts while working on an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275398/9254539) and [Preventing conflicting simultaneous edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6495). Can this be fixed? Also, if it's possible, can the rejected edit be removed from my record?

People have also pointed out that I shouldn't edit bad questions such as "It's not working, please help!" questions since they will probably get deleted anyway, and I totally agree with that.

I understand that I should have also improved the paragraph before the code, and my edit could have been rejected just because I didn't fix stuff that I could have fixed. But the same thing could have happened if there weren't any other problems with the question.

Comment: Related feature request: [Get notified of edit conflicts while working on an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275398/2675154)

Comment: Apart from the comment Hans made, it looks like you're (also) making some changes in the coding style of used in a post. That is frowned upon. See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: You should also be fixing as much as possible when suggesting edits. Your edit didn't fix any of the problems in the paragraph of text below the code. That said, there ought to have been some notification that the post was changed since you started editing. What browser/version/OS are you using and do you have any add-ons that might interfere with the site's JavaScript?

Comment: As for the previous rejects ([assuming they've fixed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362096/4076315)) edits rejected by the Community because they conflicted with another edit don't count against you. It'd be nice if they had a different term for those (there's 'disputed' for flags but that wouldn't make sense for edits) but the important thing is that they don't contribute to an edit ban.

Comment: @honk I thought this was already a feature as I sometimes get a message saying the post has been edited, but it didn't appear here.

Comment: @rene I just pasted the code into my IDE and let the formatter do the indenting and stuff, and it wasn't any different than the other edit except for some line wrapping and a few spaces. I do agree that I should have improved the paragraph below though.

Comment: @BSMP I do know about that, however, this edit was rejected for a different reason (not because it conflicted with a subsequent edit).

Comment: @BSMP I agree with you that I should have improved the paragraph below. I'm using Chrome with default settings (JavaScript allowed), and I do get a notification sometimes, but it didn't appear this time.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't completely understand what you mean by that. Are you saying the question was a bad one anyways and that I shouldn't have wasted time editing it? On an unrelated note, you *can* actually polish a turd.

Comment: "*On an unrelated note, you can actually polish a turd*" you can spend 20 years polishing that sucker, with all the love and care in the world, with the world's best turd polishing kits available to man, and 600 tonnes of elbow grease, And at the end of it all what do you have? A turd. So perhaps it *is* shinier than the most shiniest thing on national shiny day, and won "shiniest turd" 5 years running in the world shiny turd competition. It's still a turd.

Comment: @James So I shouldn't try to edit bad questions such as "please help me find the bug" questions in the future?

Comment: Personally, I go by the rule where I only edit questions that are already ok, or could be ok either by my edit and/or a little effort from the OP. If a question is bad and likely be closed and even deleted, then I won't edit. I edit dupes sometimes if I think it's good keywords and someone might end up there from a search here or Google, as it's good info and a stepping stone to the duped Q&A. Basically, anything that adds value to the site in anyway then I'd edit to make it better

Comment: @James Thanks a lot for the advice. It makes a lot of sense now that I think of it.