# Can you help me understanding this rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

To people suggesting me another post ([Post somehow edited while I'm making edit suggestion, no notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365715/post-somehow-edited-while-im-making-edit-suggestion-no-notification)) could answer my question: PLEASE, check if the suggested post has an answer. If not... how could it answer my question?

I know that this kind of questions are so specific that might be considered boring, for this reason I apologize in advance. Anyway this is the right place to understand if there is something I am missing.

A few hours ago my edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59916073/1426539) has been [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25189165). What impressed me was the merciless verdict in the reject comment:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

My suggested edits are hardly rejected, so my self esteem is not damaged. But what impresses me is the copy-and-pasted reason the doesn't match with my edit. The fact that the second *rejecter* used the same comment is impressive as well.

In details:

- It was a code only question, with non formatted code. The title was really long and contained a partial issue description
- I started my edit basically to fix code section. And moved part of the title in the issue description
- **In the meanwhile, someone else committed an edit, only with the code fix. This reduced the "delta" of my edit, but I was totally in good faith**
- The edit has been rejected. The question still has a long "halp mee" title, and the body is still code-only

Am I missing something?

If someone else fixed that title they would make me happy.

Comment: The "*copy-and-pasted reason*" is automatically generated depending on the chosen reason for rejection. Only in special cases, reviewers will use their own words.

Comment: @leonheess I didn't know it. Thank you.

Comment: Also: If I look at the edit you linked in your question, I think you actively harmed the previously good code formatting by introducing unnecessary line breaks. So even if you hadn't introduced the noise above it, rejection would have been the right call IMHO.

Comment: Sorry @leonheess, but I DO NOT have introduced unnecessary line breaks in the code section. What you see is the difference between my edit and another edit in some sneaky way was done after I started editing. I have explained it in my question.

Comment: I can't tell that from looking at the edit and neither could the reviewers who reviewed it - maybe that's the cause of the confusion. However, the code formatting that was "*sneakily*" edited in is still better than the one you proposed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post somehow edited while I'm making edit suggestion, no notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365715/post-somehow-edited-while-im-making-edit-suggestion-no-notification)

Comment: @leonheess Con I ask you why? the triple apice has exactly the same effect as indentation. Furthermore it consumes less memory and avoids _formatting malfunctioning_ due to the missing empty line between the description section and the code section.

Comment: @leonheess That question has no answer.

Comment: If you open your edit suggestion and compare the left and the right side of the *rendered output* you will see that the left version is much more readable.

Comment: @leonheess ok, you are talking about the empty lines, present in the original post, that the other editor removed. That doesn't mean that my edit was _harmful_. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: The thing is that reviewers only see what you and I are seeing on this edit. They don't know how the question looked originally. They will see the difference between the current version and your suggestion. If you think this is a problem for the aforementioned reason, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275398/get-notified-of-edit-conflicts-while-working-on-an-edit) is a feature-request you might be interested in.

Comment: @leonheess I'm definitely interested in that feature request. It demonstrates I'm a victim of a missing feature (an unmanaged race condintion) that does not deserve a -10 on his question... :)

Comment: Don't worry, votes on meta are not affecting reputation but instead are means of showing agreement or disagreement with the opinion expressed. Also, regarding your most recent edit: [Questions can be a duplicate of an unanswered question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277950/is-a-question-a-duplicate-if-the-duplicate-has-no-answers). In case you are uncertain about how Meta SO works, I encourage you to read [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206669/discussion-between-roberto-caboni-and-leonheess).

Comment: I kind of answered the duplicate in the comments (though we never found out why they didn’t get the notification). I will write a real answer post when I have time later today. I’ll try to explain what reviewers see when this sort of thing happens.

Comment: @BSMP. It would be really great if in your answer you could explain also the difference between this scenario and the one where the comment is "This edit conflicted with..." etcetera.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

The suggested edit "broke" almost as much as it "fixed".

Yes, it removed noise from the title. That's good.

But it added noise in the body of the question. The added phrase does nothing to make the question clearer. And to make things worse, it contains spelling and grammar errors.

The change in code formatting is mostly superfluous, and does not help making the question easier to understand and answer. It does bit, but it's not enough to make it a worthwhile edit. Particularly if you consider what follows:

That question would probably be better closed. It's based on a few typos/confusions (confusing the assignment operator with the equality operator, missing out on the colons after the `if` statements, confusion about how different types can be compared).

Suggesting an edit to a question that deserves closure and leaving it in a state that still deserves closure is a moot exercise, and should be avoided.

Comment: I may agree that the question was a candidate for closure. But the problem was also clear. Furthermore: I did not perform any code changes. I simply enclosed the code into code section (as the other editor did, by the way). And my body edit (though with a typo, I confess I missed it) summarized the intentions shown in that long title. A typo in an edit can be corrected. Refusing the whole edit does not make sense.

Comment: Furthermore: the purpose of an edit shall not be totally salvaging the edited question! What edits do is allow collaboration in order to achieve a continuous improvement. I see a mistake? I correct it. If I miss one on more mistakes some other people will notice and correct them.

Comment: It's **at best**, a completely superfluous edit. It does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. I wonder if I read that that somewhere? Coupled to that, it adds new errors, meaning you add more work for users down the line. And finally, for an unsalvageable question, either you salvage the post or you close it. Otherwise you would be doing the equivalent of "polishing a turd". Yeah, you can make it shiny, but it will remain smelly. That does not help.

Comment: Is an edit on a question containing code not correctly formatted really superfluous? Really? Come on... And the question WAS salvageable. Even though it was about basic coding errors, it was precisely clear what the OP was asking. And my typo had simply to be corrected by the reviewer: the edit-the-edit feature is a tool provided by SO, and that proves that is the correct way to handle this scenario.

Comment: I've already explained you my reasoning. It seems that we disagree. The reviewers also disagreed. I'm not sure I can help you any more. Good luck.

Comment: The review is gone. I'm just surprised to learn that the fix of the code section is not worth an edit. I was just trying to avoid the collapse of all my edit-beliefs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: The original question post is not salvageable because the phrase "this code isn't working" is not a problem description with which we could help. Until you get full edit privileges (2k), it is better to not edit posts which remains unsalvageable: this provides just a noise for reviewers. With full edit privileges it is acceptible to partially fix the possibly unsalvageable (but not closed!) question in hope that other editors or the asker will do remaining fixes.